# get_the_category_list how to remove uncategorized?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there a way to do this to get a category from your wordpress Permalink then get each parent category from there?  I am trying to make bread crumbs...

wp_list_categories() preformats it and gives you the uncategorized section too which I would like to remove.

```
$category_id = wp_list_categories();
echo $category_id ;
```

My categories I am testing with are:

```
Categories
    Test Prep
        Test Taking Skills
            Study Skills
    Uncategorized
```

I got this working but how do you remove Uncategorized?

```
$categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'mytheme' ) );

$category_id = get_cat_ID($categories_list);
$categories = get_categories(array('parent_of' => $category_id));
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' .       $category->name.'</a><br> ';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the ways you can do it:

#### `get_the_category_list()`

You'll need to use a filter `the_category_list`. Add this to your functions.php. If you look at the internals of `get_the_category_list()` it uses this filter to build the categories before output:

```
add_filter( 'the_category_list', static function( $categories ){
    // Loop through all the categories that are found
    foreach ( $categories as $index => $category ) {
        // if the category object slug equals "uncategorized"
        if ( $category->slug === 'uncategorized' ) :
            // remove it from the list of categories
            unset($categories[$index]);
        endif;
    }
    // return the categories
    return $categories;
});
```

#### `wp_list_categories()`

This one is a bit easier because you can pass the `exclude` argument and use the slug:

```
wp_list_categories([
   'exclude' => 'uncategorized',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the "uncategorized" category?

If not, you could set another category term to be the standard category:
Wordpress Backend to "Settings" -> "Writing" -> "Default Post Category" and choose a category term.

After that, you are able to delete it from the categories and so will not appear in get_the_category_list because it does not exist anymore.